# Identifying the iteration Scheme

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, fixed-point-iteration

The iteration

$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} (x_{n} + \frac{2}{x_{n}}) , n \ge 0$

for a given $x_{0} \ne 0$ is an instance of

1. fixed point iteration for $f(x) = x^2 - 2$.
2. Newton's method for $f(x) = x^2 - 2$.
3. fixed point iteration for $f(x) = \frac{x^2 + 2}{2x}$.
4. Newton's method for $f(x) = x^2 + 2$.

It is well known that this is Newton's method for $f(x) = x^2 - 2$.

Also solving

$x = \frac{1}{2} (x + \frac{2}{x})$    [Equivalent of writing $f(x) = 0$ as $x= g(x)$]

we get

$x^2 - 2 = 0$

which shows the given iteration is a fixed point iteration for $f(x) = x^2 - 2$.

Thus the correct options are 2 & 1 but the correct options in the key are given to be 2 & 3.

This question appeared in CSIR Dec 2015. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The key is correct. Why do you think 1 is correct? A fixed point iteration for 1 gives $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 -2$ which looks nothing like the above...

Comment: Is it so? Actually I have never studied these iteration schemes but now when I am referring articles on fixed point iteration schemes everywhere they are asking to write the original equation $f(x) = 0$ in the form $x=g(x)$ for some function $g$ . By this definition it is clearly the iteration scheme for 1. Am I wrongly interpreting the definition?

Comment: I am basically referring this article  [link](https://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/sryedida/public_html/caimna/transcendental/iteration%20methods/fixed-point/iteration.html)

Comment: A fixed point iteration for $f$ is $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$. A Newton iteration is $x_{n+1} = x_n - {f(x_n) \over f'(x_n)}$. Just evaluate these with the given $f$s and compare.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me the name for the iteration scheme(if any) which I misunderstood with the fixed point iteration scheme.

Comment: A few thoughts. 1) The article your refer to is not great and has guided you in the wrong direction. Fixed point iterations $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ are primarily useful when $g$ is contraction, a point which should be made early and not towards the end of the discussion. A good textbook is "Numerical Analysis" by David Kincaid and Ward Cheney. I can say with certainty that the 2nd and 3rd editions are good.  2) Referring to the Indian Council of Scientific and Industrial Research (CSIR) does not help anyone answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. @CarlChristian

Comment: @ShivaniGoel: See my first comment. If you apply a fixed point iteration to 1 you will get the iteration in the comment which differs from that in the question.

Comment: @copper.hat I got that. I just referred the wrong definition before posting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) A newton method iteration scheme is $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ , therefore taking $f(x) = x^2-2$ , we will get option 2 is correct and hence 1 & 4 are false.

3) A fixed point iteration scheme is given by $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$, therefore taking $f(x) = \frac{x^2+2}{2x}$ we get option 3 is correct.